# Error on copy folder from remote system using FTP

Tags: java, server, ftp

[Find the screen shot here about commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpfAO.png)I'm trying to copy folder from remote system using FTP in java and getting this error:

> Unable to determine system type - response: 502 Command not implemented.

How do I resolve this issue?

This is the code getting the 502 error:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
public class test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String server = "******";
        int port = 21;
        String user = "asassas";
        String pass = "123456";

        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();

        try {
            // connect and login to the server
            ftpClient.connect(server, port);
            ftpClient.login(user, pass);

            // use local passive mode to pass firewall
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            System.out.println("Connected");

            String remoteDirPath = "/eclipse/FB010714";
            String saveDirPath = "D:/FTPtest/Download/FTP";

            FTPUtil.downloadDirectory(ftpClient, remoteDirPath, "", saveDirPath);

            // log out and disconnect from the server
            ftpClient.logout();
            ftpClient.disconnect();

            System.out.println("Disconnected");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "How to resolve this issue?"  You will need to start by finding out **what** command is not implemented.   Use a debugger.

Comment: Show us your code. What Java FTP library are you using?

Comment: can you please check this ? @StephenC

Comment: Did you do what I suggested?

Comment: The point is that just looking at your code is unlikely to give a good answer.  What you need to do is find out **what happens** when you interact with the specific FTP server you are using, in the context of *your* networking environment.  A 502 typically happens when an FTP client tries to use an optional FTP verb that the specific server does not support.  Which verb ...

Comment: I am getting null in command, find the screen shot attached there @StephenC